# Random exceptions w/o change in code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I'm currently working on an app that loads an XML loaded with info about developers in the WinPhanDev community, and then fetches tweets by all the devs. It's also supposed to show all the published apps a particular dev has published, which is partially working.

When running the code that parses the json fetched from http://zunderstorehost.azurewebsites.net/api/ I get random exceptions without changes to the code when adding the 5th/6th or 7th developer to the collection.

The whole method that handles all the data contains this code:

```
async void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Error == null)
   {
       string _proimage = "";
       me.twitterClient = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com");
       me.tapiAuthToken = EncodeTo64(me.tapiCKey + ":" + me.tapiCSecret);
       // Authorize app for Twitter
       me.tweetReq = new RestRequest("oauth2/token", Method.POST);
       me.tweetReq.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + me.tapiAuthToken);
       me.tweetReq.AddHeader("Host", "api.twitter.com");
       me.tweetReq.AddHeader("User-Agent", "WinPhanDevs");
       me.tweetReq.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF8");
       me.tweetReq.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
       try
       {
            me.resp = await me.twitterClient.GetResponseAsync(me.tweetReq);
            me.token = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthToken>(me.resp.Content);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
            ErrorClass error = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorClass>(me.resp.Content);
            App.ViewModel.Devs.Add(new WinPhanDevs.ViewModels.DevViewModel() { Name = error.errors[0].label, Twitter = error.errors[0].message, PublisherID = ex.Message, Site = "", StoryLink = "", Image= "", Tweets = null });
       }

       XMLData = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
       var devs = from el in XMLData.Descendants("dev") select el;
       foreach (XElement el in devs)
       {
            #region "Load devs tweets"
            twts = new ObservableCollection<TweetViewModel>();
            if(el.Attribute("twitter").Value != "")
            {
                // Fetch tweets
                me.twitterClient = new RestClient(me.tapi);
                me.tweetReq = new RestRequest("search/tweets.json", Method.GET);
                me.tweetReq.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + me.token.access_token);
                me.tweetReq.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
                me.tweetReq.AddParameter("q", "from:" + el.Attribute("twitter").Value + " exclude:retweets exclude:replies");

                string[] _createdAt = new string[20];
                string[] _text = new string[20];
                string[] _link = new string[20];
                string[] _image = new string[20];

                Peep res = await ExecuteAsync<Peep>(me.tweetReq, me.tapi);
                Status[] statuses = res.statuses;

                int i = 0;
                foreach (Status tweet in statuses)
                {
                    DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(tweet.created_at, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
                    _createdAt[i] = time.ToShortDateString() + " " + time.ToShortTimeString();
                    _text[i] = tweet.text;
                    if (tweet.entities.urls.Length > 0) { _link[i] = tweet.entities.urls[0].expanded_url; _text[i] = _text[i].Replace(tweet.entities.urls[0].url, ""); } else { _link[i] = ""; }
                    if (tweet.entities.media != null) { _image[i] = tweet.entities.media[0].media_url; _text[i] = _text[i].Replace(tweet.entities.media[0].url, ""); } else { _image[i] = ""; }
                    twts.Add(new WinPhanDevs.ViewModels.TweetViewModel() { Date = _createdAt[i], Tweet = _text[i], Link = _link[i] });
                    i++;
                }
                _proimage = statuses[0].user.profile_image_url;
            }
            #endregion
            #region "Load devs apps"
            // Gets an IndexOutOfBounds/TargetInvocation/NullReference
            // exception in here while adding the 5th/6th or 7th developer,
            // none of the exceptions are caught.
            // Without this whole region the app runs smooth.
            try
            {
                RestClient devClient = new RestClient("http://zunderstorehost.azurewebsites.net/api/");
                string dev = el.Attribute("pubid").Value;
                //dev = dev.Replace(" ", "+");
                RestRequest devReq = new RestRequest("WP8StoreAppList/Query/" + dev, Method.GET);
                response = await devClient.GetContentAsync(devReq);
                AppClass[] apps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppClass[]>(response);
                Apps = new ObservableCollection<AppViewModel>();
                foreach (AppClass app in apps)
                {
                    string _price;
                    if (app.Offers.Count > 1)
                    {
                        if (app.Offers[0].Price != "0")
                        {
                            _price = app.Offers[0].DisplayPrice + " (Trial available)";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _price = app.Offers[1].DisplayPrice + " (Trial available)";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (app.Offers[0].Price == "0")
                        {
                            _price = "FREE";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _price = app.Offers[0].DisplayPrice;
                        }
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        Apps.Add(new AppViewModel()
                        {
                            Name = app.Name,
                            ReleaseDate = app.ReleaseDate,
                            GUID = app.Guid,
                            Icon = app.Icon,
                            Price = _price,
                            Publisher = app.Publisher,
                            Version = app.Version,
                            StoreLink = ""
                        });
                    }catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Devs.Add(new DevViewModel() { Name = "Failed to add!", Apps = null, Image = "", PublisherID = "", Site="", StoryLink="", Tweets=null, Twitter=ex.Message});
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Devs.Add(new DevViewModel() { Name = "Failed to add!", Apps = null, Image = "", PublisherID = "", Site = "", StoryLink = "", Tweets = null, Twitter = ex.Message });
            }
            #endregion
            try
            {
                Devs.Add(new DevViewModel() { Name = el.Attribute("name").Value, Twitter = el.Attribute("twitter").Value, Site = el.Attribute("web").Value, PublisherID = el.Attribute("pubid").Value, StoryLink = el.Attribute("story").Value, Tweets = twts, Image = _proimage, Apps = Apps });
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Devs.Add(new DevViewModel() { Name = "Failed to add!", Apps = null, Image = "", PublisherID = "", Site = "", StoryLink = "", Tweets = null, Twitter = ex.Message });
            }
        }
        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Devs.Add(new DevViewModel() { Name = e.Error.Source, Twitter = e.Error.Message, PublisherID = e.Error.InnerException.Message, Site = "", StoryLink = "" });
    }
}
```

The whole project is available at https://github.com/IzaacJ/WinPhanDevs and the particular file this problem occurs is the MainViewModel.cs

Any help in solving this issue will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide more information on what is the exception (including eventually inner exception), the line where it occurred and eventually the stack trace

Comment: The line is the `Devs.Add(new DevViewModel() { Name = el.Attribute("name").Value, Twitter = el.Attribute("twitter").Value, Site = el.Attribute("web").Value, PublisherID = el.Attribute("pubid").Value, StoryLink = el.Attribute("story").Value, Tweets = twts, Image = _proimage, Apps = Apps });`. And according to the exception object, there is no InnerException. This seems to be what caused the NullReferenceException.

Comment: Found one bug in your code, if you navigate away and navigate back while the page is loading (or the lock screen popup), App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded will still be false so you end up with two call of LoadData at the same time which can cause a lot of problem

Comment: Okey thanks for informing that. Will make sure it won't load twice :) It seems that the exceptions actually are caused by malformed JSON data from the twitter api. The search metadata shows 15 tweets, but the statuses section is empty. The full response is available here: http://pastebin.com/BdxwfU5X